# Why can't I catch a TypeError with set_error_handler()?

Tags: php, exception, types, error-handling, function-declaration

Here is code:

```
<?php
function hola(int $hola)
{
    return $hola;
}
function handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    echo 'handler';
}
set_error_handler("handler");
hola('hola');
```

Here is Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: hola(): Argument #1 ($hola) must be
> of type int, string given, called in
> C:\laragon\www\estudiophp\script.php on line 12 and defined in
> C:\laragon\www\estudiophp\script.php:2 Stack trace: #0
> C:\laragon\www\estudiophp\script.php(12): hola('hola') #1 {main}
> thrown in C:\laragon\www\estudiophp\script.php on line 2

Answer (score 1):

The `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError:` is an exception, not an error. To capture exceptions you need to register a [exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). Using your `handler` function as an example, here is what an exception handler would look like.

```
function exception_handler($exception)
{
    echo 'Exception Handler';
}
set_exception_handler("exception_handler");
```

You are able to use both the `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler` functions together to capture both errors and exceptions separately.

```
function exception_handler($exception)
{
    echo 'Exception Handler';
}
function handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    echo 'Handler';
}
set_exception_handler("exception_handler");
set_error_handler("handler");
```

Comment: As a note, it was PHP7 that began changing a number of "classic" errors into throwable error objects.

Comment: hi @Austen Holland I didn't know that, the question arose because in this link it is said that TypeError extends the Error class, I got confused and that's why I asked https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php

Comment: hi @Sammitch, it's related to the comment I made above, right?

Comment: Yes, the Error type has a somewhat complicated heritage due to how new it is. It purposely does not extend the Exception class, but is still virtually identical. It is a logical distinction more than anything else, to prevent code like `catch(Exception $e)` from catching Errors. That said, for various reasons some functionality was not duplicated, eg: global exception handlers catching Errors as well.

Comment: @Sammitch "global exception handlers catching Errors as well" - That's true, I checked, as long as you set the type `Throwable`, thanks